# Chocolately installed additional softwares

Tags: python, powershell, chocolatey

today i installed pandoc (pandoc is used for converting markdown files to html) using chocolatey, it installed succesfully, i have pandoc, but reading the logs, i found this:

```
`2021-10-05 10:14:50,746 19684 [INFO ] - python;visualstudio2017-workload-vctools
2021-10-05 10:14:50,746 19684 [INFO ] - By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
2021-10-05 10:14:50,824 19684 [WARN ] -
```

> python is not installed. Installing...

```
2021-10-05 10:14:50,840 19684 [DEBUG] - Using 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.
2021-10-05 10:14:51,339 19684 [DEBUG] - - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
2021-10-05 10:14:51,339 19684 [DEBUG] - - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
2021-10-05 10:14:51,620 19684 [DEBUG] - Package 'python' found on source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'`
```

I have python already installed on my pc, so, my question is: did chocolatey installed another python?
P.S. the command i runned on powershell was : `choco install pandoc`

Comment: you can check your system for python installations:

`dir "{Drive letter}:\ /s /b | find "python.exe"`

Comment: @JoshSharkey i tried rn, and it isnt showing anything

Comment: check your syntax, no output means python isnt installed.

Comment: My drive letter is C so I use: `dir C:\  /s /b | find "python.exe"`

Comment: @JoshSharkey now i tried again, but its showing an error: dir C:\  /s /b | find "python.exe"
Get-ChildItem : Impossibile trovare un parametro posizionale che accetta l'argomento '/b'.
In riga:1 car:1
+ dir C:\  /s /b | find "python.exe"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @T69 If you run ```dir``` in a Powershell prompt it's an alias for ```Get-ChildItem``` rather than the shell's ```dir``` command (see ```Get-Alias dir```), so your error is saying "Get-ChildItem doesn't have a parameter you can pass ```/b``` to". Try ```dir C:\  /s /b | find "python.exe"``` at a command prompt instead.